# shell scripts not executing and showing only the command as log with -c in front

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting

I am new to Unix scripting and suddenly encountered an issue where my scripts are only logging, for example

```
$ ssh user@mainframe pwd
-c pwd
$ ssh user@mainframe rm -rf dir-name
-c rm -rf dir-name
```

Previously it would show the present working directory but now it would only show the command with a '-c' in front.  This happens to all commands and no execution actually happens.

I have no clue what to check or set.

Comment: Try checking whether you are really running `ssh` with the `which` and `alias` commands. i.e. `which ssh` should return the path of the ssh executable (ssh is not built into the shell, but your path can hijack access to the incorrect file).

Comment: Thanks Richard.  tried 'which ssh' and showed 'usr/bin/ssh'.  I asked a colleague to execute the same script and it went normally, same  path 'usr/bin/ssh' and executed the commands.  It seems something in my profile is making my execution different.

Comment: Check what shell is set for the "user" account on the mainframe. You could get this behavior if the shell was set to "/bin/echo" for example.

Comment: Thanks Kenster for the input.  I have finally resolved and it related to another level of our rights having expired for my profile.

Answer (score 0):

It actually relates to another level of our rights that expired already for my profile, preventing my commands from being executed.